# ASP.NET Voice Recognition Application

Tags: asp.net, voice

.
Dear All,
                 We are working on an ASP.NET Voice Recognition Project.  The application is mainly aimed in training the end user in English Language.  Here we need to capture the voice of what the logged-in user speaks against a displayed image.

For example we need to capture & send the recorded voice of user “A man is driving a car” to the server when we show an image of a man driving a car in the webpage.

After this and at server end we need to convert this voice into text and then compare with the database text “A man is driving a car”. If both matches then the user gets 1 point else 0 points.

So would you please guide us how to carry-out the development of this application.  Reference links would be of great help.

Many Thanks,
Regards
Anupriya. 
.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'd be able to do this without some kind of browser plug-in.  It might be possible with Silverlight, although it's not something I've tried.

If you haven't seen it already, the MS Speech API provides speech-to-text (and vice versa) and comes free with many versions of Windows, not sure about servers though.  There is a [managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx) and an [unmanaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627%28VS.85%29.aspx) version.

Silverlight 4 can access the user's microphone, so you should be able to record the speech, send it back, and process it on the server using the speech API.

[This post](http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/07/text-to-speech-in-silverlight-using-wcf/) creates an example app which does the reverse (text in the browser gets converted to speech at the server and returned to the client), but some of the principles should be the same.

[This sample app](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/nipuntomar/3385/Default.) does speech-to-text using WPF.

Good luck!